# Does any irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{R} [x]$ with degree $n$ necessarily have $n$ equally spaced roots around a circle on the Argand diagram?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

More precisely: Does any polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R} [x]$ which is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$ with $deg(f) = n$ necessarily have roots in $\mathbb{C}$ of the form $\{Ke^{2(k/n)\pi i}, Ke^{2(k+1/n)\pi i}, \cdots, Ke^{2(k+(n-1)/n)\pi i}\}$ where $k \in [0,1)$ and $K \in \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Only for $x^n-K^n=0$... ?

Comment: In $\Bbb R[x]$, the only irreducible polynomials are linear or quadratic. I suspect you meant $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: To Paul Garrett: $x^2 + 2^2 = 0$ has roots $\pm 2i$ which can be written as $\{ 2e^{(1/2)\pi i}, 2e^{(3/2)\pi i}\}$

Comment: To Arthur: Not something I realised, to be honest. I am still curious about $\mathbb{R}[x]$ but now I'm interested in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ too!

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of your comment to paul garrett is supposed to be. Note that $\{\pm i\}$ is not of the form $\{\alpha^k\}$ for an $n$th root of unity $\alpha$ because it's missing $\pm1$, so your example does not contradict paul's comment. To add to paul's comment, if the roots of the polynomial are $\{ K\alpha^k\}$ then the polynomial must be $\prod (x-K\alpha^k)$ which equals $x^n-K^n$. That's the **only** kind of polynomial for which the roots are $\{K\alpha^k\}$. Any other polynomial has a different set of roots.

Comment: To runway44: Ah damn, I massively blundered my question. I meant "roots in $\mathbb{C}$ of the form $\{Ke^{2(k/n)\pi i}, Ke^{2(k+1/n)\pi i}, \cdots, Ke^{2(k+(n-1)/n)\pi i}\}$ for $k \in [0,1)$ and $K \in \mathbb{R}$", my bad!

Comment: You can just factor $e^{2k\pi i/n}$ out of those exponentials and absorb it into the $K$ and it's the same question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Consider $f(x)=x^2+x+1$, for a counterexample.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough. Is there a rule about the conditions required in order to get roots in $\mathbb{C}$ of the form $\{K\alpha, K\alpha^2, \cdots, K\alpha^{n-1}\}$ where $\alpha$ is a root of unity and $K \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $(x-K)(x-K\alpha)(x-K\alpha^2)\cdots(x-K\alpha^{n-1})= x^n-K^n$, as commented above by @runway44

Comment: Yes, sorry I misdefined what I meant by, "equally spaced around a circle in the argand diagram". This is the definition I meant: "roots in $\mathbb{C}$ of the form $\{Ke^{2(k/n)\pi i}, Ke^{2(k+1/n)\pi i}, \cdots, Ke^{2(k+(n-1)/n)\pi i}\}$ for $k \in (0,1)$ and $K \in \mathbb{R}$". Apologies.

Comment: * $k \in [0,1)$